# Sets and Sequences

Tags: definition

My question is basically: true or false? I'm told this is false, but don't understand why.

- Set: A set is an unordered group of related elements which are
  distinct.
- Sequence: A sequence is a list of related elements which
  occur in a particular order.

Comment: "Related" is debatable, and sets are not ordered.

Comment: @randall typeo on ordered, was supposed to be unordered.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Your two statements about "Set" and "Sequences" are neither true or false because  "Set" is an undefined primitive concept similar to point and line in Euclidean geometry, and "Sequence" is not precise enough to be a definition.

Answer (score 1):

A set doesn't have a specified order.  The two element set $\{1,2\}$ is the same as $\{2,1\}$.

A sequence is a list of values. You can think of a finite sequence of length $n$ as a function on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  An infinite sequence is a function on the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a set is a somewhat complicated discussion as evident by Russel's paradox.The definition by Cantor (as taken from wikipedia) is "A set is a gathering together into a whole of definite, distinct objects of our perception or of our thought—which are called elements of the set." .The formality about what is a set can be explored through the axioms proposed by Ernst Zermelo and Abraham Fraenkel.

A sequence can be defined to be a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$ where $A$ is a set.